# React onchange function on slider to an html img

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Im trying to change the style whenever ReactSlider is changed. I want to add for example brightness when slider is increased in React. I did it but I cannot seem to get the styles to be added to the image whenever the slider goes through the onchange event. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BsFileEarmarkPlus } from 'react-icons/bs';
import ReactSlider from 'react-slider';

class Edit extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            file: null,
        }
        this.ImageUpload = this.ImageUpload.bind(this);
        this.ChangeImage = this.ChangeImage.bind(this);
    }

    ImageUpload(event) {
        console.log(event.target.files[0]);
        this.setState({
            file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
        });
    }

    ChangeImage(props) {
        console.log(props);
        var amount = this.props + '%';
        var imgStyles = {
            filter: 'brightness(' + amount + ')'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="editor">
                <h1>Editor</h1>
                <label htmlFor="fileChoose"><BsFileEarmarkPlus />Upload
                    <input type="file" id="fileChoose" onChange={this.ImageUpload} />
                </label>
                <hr />
                <div className="img-surround">
                <img 
                    src={this.state.file} 
                    id="img"
                    style={imgStyles} />
                </div>

                <div className="edit-nav">
                    <ReactSlider
                    className="horizontal-slider"
                    defaultValue={0}
                    max={100}
                    min={-100}
                    thumbClassName="example-thumb"
                    trackClassName="example-track"
                    renderThumb={(props, state) => <div {...props}>{state.valueNow}</div>}
                    onChange={this.ChangeImage}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Edit;
```

The only problem is imgStyles is undefined when called from outside the render(). Everything else works.

Comment: interesting perhaps step through or add logging to make sure the right elements are being updated

Comment: I did the console.log() of imgStyles. it returned exactly as it is defined in the code example. the only thing was that they said props was an [object Object] but when logging the props by itself it gave the current value of the slider. Removing this.props to props actually worked to change value so thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you defined 'imgStyles' variable in 'ChangeImage' function.
You should define this variable out of class or define it as state variable.

```
var imgStyles = {};
class Edit extends React.Component {
...

 ChangeImage(props) {
  console.log(props);
  var amount = this.props + '%';
  imgStyles = {
   filter: 'brightness(' + amount + ')'
  }
 }
...
```

Or

```
...
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   file: null,
   imgStyles: {}
  }
 }
...

ChangeImage(props) {
  console.log(props);
  var amount = this.props + '%';
  this.setState({ imgStyles: { filter: 'brightness(' + amount + ')' } });
}
...
     <img 
      src={this.state.file} 
      id="img"
      style={this.state.imgStyles} />
...
```